# Previous Year YTD till Same Date

Tags: date, powerpivot, dax, ssas-tabular

I have requirement, Previous Year YTD till the same date as YTD is returing results for example if the Records in my table is present from 1-jan-2016 to 9-May-2016 then this year YTD will Calculate till 9-May-2016 (this is Working fine ) and Previous year YTD also should calculate till 9-May-2015 from 1-Jan-2015 not for whole year or whole month

I had tried all the solutions mentioned here :- [DAX Pattern](http://www.daxpatterns.com/time-patterns/)

[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b89ba3c8-806f-4110-b6e6-36b467d08be4/fiscal-ytd-and-compare-fiscal-period-to-date?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel)

But didnt get any result yet,

Comment: Can you post the formulas you are using. 
The problem is probably that you are selecting a whole month in your selection. So YTD will take into account the full month. 
You can avoid this behaviour by using the function lastnonblank() function.

Comment: @WimV I tried with last non blank too, here is the formula Revenue YTD PY:=CALCULATE([Revenue],LASTNONBLANK('Date Master'[Date],[Revenue]),DATESBETWEEN('Date Master'[Date],
FIRSTDATE(DATEADD('Date Master'[Date],-12,MONTH)),
LASTDATE(DATEADD('Sales Details'[InvoiceDate2],-12,MONTH))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many solutions finally got the solutions which solves my purpose.

In my fact table I added a column named Invoicedate and format is "YYYYMMDD" the similar column in Date table names as Datekey and fomrat is "YYYYMMDD".

Here is the calculation for YTD:

```
Revenue YTD:=CALCULATE([Revenue],DATESYTD('Date Master'[Date],"03-31"),ALL('Date Master'))
```

And the Here is the calculation for Previous Year YTD:-

```
Revenue PY:=CALCULATE([Revenue YTD],FILTER(ALL('Date Master'[Datekey]),FILTER(VALUES('Sales Details'[InvoiceDate]),'Sales Details'[InvoiceDate]-10000=EARLIER('Date Master'[Datekey]))),ALL('Date Master'))
```

Benefit of this solution is, it handles the leap year issue well. I got the idea of this solution from :- [Chris Webb's BI Blog](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2010/05/26/time-intelligence-without-date-columns-in-dax/)